# Add binding to dynamically created element

Tags: ractivejs

When dynamically adding an element to the DOM, is it possible to add a binding to it?

```
var element = $('#div1').after('<span></span>');
element.data("name", ???);  // create binding equivalent to data-name="{{Name}}"
```

I know that I could use `ractive.observe()` to watch changes to the keypath and update the element accordingly, but the binding syntax is more concise so I'm hoping I can still leverage it.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9mo3qrw/1/) that shows how I'm using `ractive.observe()`.

Comment: Not really, no. You'd almost certainly be better off avoiding that kind of imperative DOM manipulation - can you outline the scenario in which you currently need to do `.after('...')` in more detail?

Comment: @RichHarris See the JSFiddle link in my update. It's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. `.observe()` works well, I was just wondering if there was an even better way.

Comment: Generally the best approach is to write the content into the template, because then you don't need to glue the two systems together - e.g. [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/vduseb87/). If that's repetitive, you can always use partials or [components](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/sgg0rygn/)

Comment: Thanks @RichHarris! Btw Ractive is awesome.